# How to take and print a paragraph from console scanner?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to take a paragraph as input from the console and convert it to one string (with `\n`'s and `\t`'s and everything). My code never realizes that the user is done inputting, I don't understand why. Enter just takes me to the next line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What is the paragraph?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = "";
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        if(!scanner.hasNext()){
            break;
        } else {
            s+=scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: How will the program know that you don't want to introduce a new input? Do you want to have a special line (like "exit" / "stop"). Do you want to use a timeout?

Comment: OK that makes sense. i changed that, and it worked.

Comment: One easy termination is to check if the next line is an empty String.  For the user, pressing the Enter key twice.